# Which form has been submitted from <button> element (with type as button)

Tags: php, jquery, forms, button

I have search a lot but I couldn't find / understand a way to solve this.

I have to forms in the same page.

```
<form id="inquiry_theme_form" name="inquiry_theme_form" action"#" method="post">

                                /*Some fields etc*/

<button type="button" value="Go" id="inq_btn_sumbit" name="inq_btn_sumbit">Go</button>
</form>

<form id="booking_form" name="booking_form" action"#" method="post">

                              /*Some fields etc*/

<button type="button" name="book_btn_submit" id="book_btn_submit">Book now</button>
</form>
```

I set the type of buttons to button because I want to validate some fields before posting. So If the user has fill all the fields I post the form with jquery.

```
$("#inq_btn_sumbit").click(function() {
var the_form = $("#inquiry_theme_form");

                /* Validation */
         if(error){
                 /*Warn the user*/
        }
        else{
            the_form.submit();
        }
});

$("#book_btn_submit").click(function() {
var the_form = $("#booking_form");

                /* Validation */
         if(error){
                 /*Warn the user*/
        }
        else{
            the_form.submit();
        }
});
```

On the same page where I have the forms I have this code at the top of the page.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
       /*I WANT HERE TO SOMEHOW CHECK WHICH FORM HAS BEEN SUBMITTED*/
}
```

So how I can identify which button the user press namely which form has been submitted

Sorry for my English and thanks for your help!!

Comment: set a hidden field in each of your form with different values, and check them on server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check which one was submited using a `<input type="hidden" name="form" value"form1" />`.

Comment: I usually either do that, or i'll use a url variable in the form's declaration action="" url attribute. Like <form action="process.php?sender=secondForm">.  Then, I'll use a $_GET['sender'] to give my script the variable from the url.